# How 4-vector nature of the value is connected with it's conservation law?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, conservation-laws

In electrodynamics Poynting vector and energy flux of field don't create 4-vector. Also they aren't conserved independently from substance (conservation law includes summand connected with current density). 
In linearized gravity mass density and mass current density as components of stress-energy tensor also aren't conserved. And they also aren't components of 4-vector.

Is facts of non-conservation of values above connected with the absense of 4-vector nature?

Comment: Note that the Poynting vector is absorbed into the [electromagnetic stress tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress-energy_tensor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no connection between transformation properties of an object (4-vectorness) and it conservation under time evolution.

As you can guess the conservation law should be related to the dynamics of the system and hence it should be expressed in such terms like a Lagrangian, Hamiltonian etc. In the most general case conservation of a quantity is ruled by the Noether theorem and is related to the symmetries of a system. E.g. is a system is symmetric under shifts in time energy is conserved.

Then you can think of symmetries with respect to rotations that leads to conservation of angular momentum, that is not a 4-vector as well.

Comment: Thank you. I was stupid, because the argument of my question may be used for each of 4-vector of momentum.

Comment: Asking stupid question is a way to learn things :)